# Special characters at end of javascript file

Tags: javascript, citrix

I am needing some advise on this weird issue im running into randomly which i havent been able to figure out yet.

I am writing some javascript code on my local desktop at work and moving the file via citrix session to the right static content folder. Randomly i start getting script errors on code that worked before. Upon accessing the content of the js file through the URL that is being used to render it, i start seeing multiple lines of:"���������������������������������������������������" at the end of the javascript file.

Initially i thought some how the encoding was changing while saving the file, but i have tried to enforce various encodings and the issue still persists. I have also tried various text editors such as notepad, notepad++, sublime text.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be happening here that would be causing these � to be appended at the end of the file?

Comment: You did not say what encoding the file is saved in, but what you showed is a series of the Unicode `U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` character, also used for UTF BOMs.  Do you see these characters in the file on your local machine, or only after transferring the file to the server? If the latter, is sounds like the transfer is corrupting the file.  Is that the only way you have to transfer the file?  Can you use something else, like FTP?

Comment: hey, thanks for replying. Honestly, i have tried several different encoding and i get that special character no matter what. I am checking to see if i can use a FTP program to move the file. Right now i just copy/paste from my local to the static content folder on the citrix server. I dont see these special characters when i see the file locally. What encoding should i be using for a javascript file?

Comment: Just posting to say that I have the same issue. After editing a Javascript file, which originally worked, it no longer works and the last line in my browser is just ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������.